# bcrypt Error: data and hash arguments required

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

I am getting a bcrypt error stating that data and hash arguments are required, referencing line #44 in my routes.js file. From what I can tell, I am passing that information: the first parameter to bcrypt.compare is the user entered password, and the second is the hashed password retrieved from the db. What am I doing wrong?

```
bcrypt.compare(req.params.password, user.password, function...
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../app/models/user');
//password hashing
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var count = 0;

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    count++;
    console.log('API hit count = %s', count);
    next();
});

// /users post(create new user) get(specific user)
router.route('/users')
    .post(function(req,res) {
        var user = new User();
        user.username = req.body.username;
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);

        //save the user and checkfor errors
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json({message: "User created!"});
            }    
        });

    })

router.route('/users/:username')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        var query = {
            username: req.params.username,
        };
        User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { 
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                bcrypt.compare(req.params.password, user.password, function(err, res) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log('Comparison error: ', err);
                    }
                })
                res.json(user);
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint right before `bcrypt.compare` is called and see what `req.params.password` and `user.password` are.

Comment: @bejado Dammit, I had a mistake in my app.js, sending in an undefined password. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`bcrypt.compare` takes 3 parameters; passwordToCheck, passwordHash, and a callback, respectively. [(Check the documentation for examples)](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#to-check-a-password)

This error means one or both of the first 2 parameters are either null or undefined. Therefore, make sure both of them are passed correctly. (Not as null or undefined)

Comment: This can also happen when you are using `arrow function` syntax, instead of normal `function()` syntax. So, make sure to use the latter syntax if you want to preserve `this` coming from the model, i.e., when pulling something out of the current schema. This saved my day. Thanks!!!

Comment: The await syntax does not require the third argument. My issue was one of the two arguments did not have the value I expected, so fixing that fixed this issue.

Answer (score 8):

Why do we face this error?
`bcrypt Error: data and hash arguments required`

**Example**:
`bcrypt.compare(first, second)`

**Ans**:
because either second key hash password **does not exist** (null or undefined) or first, which are compared to each other.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 5):

I used

```
const user = await User.find({email: req.body.email}) //which returned all users
```

//and unless i reference the first user in index 0, i can't pass user.password to the //bcrypt compare method because it's not a string
I changed it to

```
await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})//from which i can use user.password in the //bcrypt compare method
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same error when I was working with node js and mongoose. It was caused by attribute added to password called `select: false` in user model.

After remove it, it works.

Comment: this was what I encountered too, pretty disgusting bug but thanks to god I've found it before losing hours :D

Answer (score 2):

```
const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
```

Make sure you are giving raw password and hash password. This will return a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the problem was a missing `await` when calling the function that reads from database

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, but I was using the synchronous form of `bycrypt.compare()`, which is `bcrypt.compareSync()`, so I changed it to `bcrypt.compare()` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the steps for this problem :
1-ensure that the bcrypt function is have awir before it
2- if the problem is still exist ,then the problem is in the database (mongodb),try to create new database
an example:

```
const match = await bcrypt.compare(password,userValid.password);
            if (match) {
                res.send("login successful")
            }else{
                res.send("wrong password")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
findOne({})
```

instead of

```
find()
```

Try `console.log()` to view and verify the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    let match  = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    if(!match){
        return  res.json({mass: "invalid Created"})
    }else{
       res.send('Wrong password')
    }

    console.log('success fulli', user)
    res.render('pages/auth/login', {title: 'Login In Your Account'})

} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    next(e)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this code please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem also can appear when you forget to add await when loading data from the database.
I got the same error after forgetting to add "await".

`let user = User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });`

`let user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });`

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem i set for password `select:false` in user model and solved by adding `select('+password')` to login route

Answer (score 0):

i know all the questions are solved but maybe someone finds this code works for him

```
const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.rows[0].s_password);
```

The name after the dot it's the name you use in your database, it's the field

Comment: Btw i'm using flutter and nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, found out that I had missed an `await` while comparing hence receiving a null value when comparing.

```
// Compare incoming & stored password
const matchedPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, userExists.password)
```

Also, the first argument should be the plain text password while the second is the hashed password.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys huddle up!

First of all if you have "select":false for password in your schema,
you should use it like this:

```
const {email,passord} = req.body

const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password'); // that will allow us the edit password property without revealing it.
```

After that you can call your compare function

```
if (!(await user.comparePassword(password, user.password))) {
      res.status(400).json({
        status: 'Fail',
        msg: 'Incorrect nickname or password',
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. I realized that usermodel.find() returns an array of all users but users.findOne() returns an object. You should use the latter.