# mongoose.save() has two types of behaviour

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm learning mongoose and I'm making a simple post request to add a user to my mongolab test database. I am using a basic user schema but when I run the save() method I sometimes get an

> Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: data and salt
>   arguments required

and sometimes nothing happens, the app simply does nothing. I'm using Postman to test the post request.

**Edit**: As mikey suggested I removed the Resolve and Reject callbacks and treated everything inside the .save() callback, but now I get the following error:

> (node:10964) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's
>   default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise
>   library instead: http:// mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var mPromise = require("mpromise");

var User = require('./models/user');

var app = express();


mongoose.connect('mongodb://root2:1234@ds161742.mlab.com:61742/ecommerce', function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log("Connected to the database");
});

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/create-user", function (req, res, next) {

    var user = new User();

    user.profile.name = req.body.name;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.email = req.body.email;

    user.save(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("deu erro");
        } else {
            console.log("Deu bom");
            res.send("deu bom");
        }
    })
})


app.get("/get-users", function (req, res, next) {
    User.find({})
        .exec(function (err, users) {
            if (err) res.send("Erro na hora de pegar os usuarios " + err);
            res.send(users);
        });
});



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Deu mais bom");
});



app.listen(80, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Server is running on port 80");
});
```

Also when I connect to mongolab I get the warning:

> DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use
>   `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `conn
>   ect()` or `createConnection()`. See
>   http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client Server is
>   running on port 80 Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be
>   available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow
>   auth against users in the admin  db and will no longer allow multiple
>   credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect
>   with auth credentials.

but I'm not using any open() methods in my code since I'm not using the default mongoDB library. I was able to add a collection to the mongolab database but the data was incomplete, and now I'm struggling with this.

**Edit2**: Here is the code of my UserSchema that uses bcrypt:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/* The user schema attributes/fields */
var UserSchema = new Schema ({
    email : String,
    password: String,




    profile: {
        name: {type: String, default: "Sem nome"},
        picture: {type: String, default: ''}
    },

    address: String,
    history: [{
        date: Date,
        paid: {type: Number, default: 0},
        //item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: ''}
    }]
});

/* The method to hash the password before saving it to the database */

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;
    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
        if(err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash){
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});


/* Compare the password between the database and the input from the user */

UserSchema.methods.comparePasswords = function(inputpassword){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(inputpassword, this.password);
}


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Using `then` and `catch` with the `save` seems so unnecessary. Just handle everything within the callback.

Comment: @Mikey ok, but the code is not responding to anything even with or without the resolve and reject calls. I still get the "Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1):  Error: data and salt arguments required"

Comment: What's your user schema look like?  I'm guessing you're using a library to hash passwords, and not providing it the right kind of information (i.e. the data and salt).

Comment: Are you by chance using `bcrypt` somewhere in your code? Most answers on SO about this error relate to `bcrypt`.

Comment: yes I am, i will edit the code to the bcrypt @Mikey

Comment: @Paul I thgouth about that too, i will upload the code of my schema

Comment: Dunno, looks right.  Try logging the salt and 'user.password' to see if either is null (or when it's null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, [bcrypt.hash()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#to-hash-a-password) accepts 3 arguments not 4. Therefore, its callback probably never gets fired.

It should be simply

```
bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash){
    if(err) return next(err);
    user.password = hash;
    next();
});
```

You might also want to check that [`user.password` and `salt` are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44355355/1022914).

Comment: I, absolutely, fell like a complete douchebag right now. I added that null before i thought about adding the call back, because i'm following an Udemy course. I forgot to erase the null after I created the callback. Well it happens, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your first warning, regarding `mpromise`, you can use the native `Promise` (Node version >= 6) by doing this:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

To resolve your second warning, you have to use `useMongoClient` and the [`documentation`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client) suggests a promise approach:

```
function connectDatabase(databaseUri) {
    var promise = mongoose.connect(databaseUri, {
        useMongoClient: true,
    });

    return promise;
}

connectDatabase('mongodb://root2:1234@ds161742.mlab.com:61742/ecommerce')
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to the database");)
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

below code may solve all your issues

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var options = {
        useMongoClient:true
    };
    var dbUrl = 'mongodb://root2:1234@ds161742.mlab.com:61742/ecommerce';

    mongoose.connect(dbUrl,options);
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Comment: that did remove the warnings when I tried toconnect tothe mongoLab server, thank you very much