# Custom database connection with Node.JS and Auth0

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, auth0

I'm trying to get a custom database in Auth0 to work using Node.JS and this is what I got so far:

```
  connection.connect();

  var query = "SELECT id, username, email, passwort FROM login WHERE email = ?";

  connection.query(query, [email], function (err, results) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    if (results.length === 0) return callback(new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));
    var user = results[0];

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isValid) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
      } else if (!isValid) {
        callback(new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));
      } else {
        callback(null, {
          id: user.id.toString(),
          nickname: user.nickname,
          email: user.email
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

but when I try my script it say's "data and hash arguments required".
I bet a beer with you guys, that the error I made is extremely stupid...
Cheers

Comment: Either `password` or `user.password` is not what you think it is. Log them to the console and see what you've got

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241113/bcrypt-error-data-and-hash-arguments-required