# Express Node.js Async promises alignment issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a login in an web app, which reads from the MongoDB and sorts it into the sorted array using lodash. The problem is that my `console.log("sorted in /api/login:", sorted);` for some reason returns nothing, which doesn't make `console.log` output yeet... How do I fix this? I already tried putting some more awaits, but that didn't help me. What is this promise alignment everyone is talking about? I can't find any info online about it..

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const User = require('./models/user.js');
var _ = require('lodash');
const sorted = [];
User.find({},{ firstname: 1, password: 1 }, async function(err, users) {
  const flattenUsers = _(users).map(({firstname, password}) => ([firstname, password])).flatten().value();
  console.log(flattenUsers);
  const sorted = await flattenUsers.reduce((a, e, i) => (i % 2 || a.push([]), a[a.length - 1].push(e), a), []);
  await console.log("sorted:", sorted);
});

app.post('/api/login', apiLimiter, async function (req, res){
  try  {
    console.log("sorted in /api/login:", sorted);
    console.log("Req firstname: ",req.body.firstname)
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    console.log("Hashed pw: ", hashedPassword);
    console.log(await bcrypt.compare('testtest',hashedPassword));
    // const user = { id: req.body.id, username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password };
    var user = new User({firstname: req.body.firstname, eMail: req.body.eMail, password: hashedPassword });
    sorted.forEach(async ([eMail, password]) => {
      await bcrypt.compare(password, users[eMail]).then((e, r) => {
        // r = true if hash = hashed pw
        console.log("Yeet");
      });
    });
    jwt2.sign({user}, 'secrethere', { expiresIn: '15min'}, (err, token) =>{
    res.json({
      token
    });
  });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

My user.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  lastname: String,
  eMail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: String,
  active: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

**Update**

Errors I get when implementing the recommended answer:

> (node:17080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: users
>   is not defined
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:38
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:17080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:17080) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:17080)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: users is not defined
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:38
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:17080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:17080)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: users is not defined
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:38
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:17080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

**Update2**

> (node:11252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash arguments 
>   required
>       at Object.compare (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:209:17)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object.module.exports.promise (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
>       at Object.compare (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:205:25)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:20
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:11252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:11252) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:11252)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash arguments
>   required
>       at Object.compare (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:209:17)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object.module.exports.promise (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
>       at Object.compare (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:205:25)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:20
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:11252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:11252)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash arguments
>   required
>       at Object.compare (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:209:17)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object.module.exports.promise (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)
>       at Object.compare (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:205:25)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:20
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:11252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

**Update 3**

Now I get these errors:

> (node:14268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash
>   arguments required
>       at Object.compareSync (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:167:15)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:20
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:14268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:14268) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:14268)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash arguments
>   required
>       at Object.compareSync (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:167:15)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:20
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:14268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:14268)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data and hash arguments
>   required
>       at Object.compareSync (C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:167:15)
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:252:20
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Users\User\Documents\Carina\Canopus\src\app.js:251:12 (node:14268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call a route in express that is function that starts from app.post('/api/login', apiLimiter, async function (req, res).

So this code never gets called, just put this inside function (inside of try) and everything should work

```
const sorted = [];
User.find({},{ firstname: 1, password: 1 }, async function(err, users) {
  const flattenUsers = _(users).map(({firstname, password}) => ([firstname, password])).flatten().value();
  console.log(flattenUsers);
  const sorted = await flattenUsers.reduce((a, e, i) => (i % 2 || a.push([]), a[a.length - 1].push(e), a), []);
  await console.log("sorted:", sorted);
});
```

UPDATE, working code with function

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
const User = require('./models/user.js');
var _ = require('lodash');

async function getSorted(){
const sorted = [];
let users = await User.find({},{ firstname: 1, password: 1 });
  const flattenUsers = _(users).map(({firstname, password}) => ([firstname, password])).flatten().value();
  console.log(flattenUsers);
  const sorted = await flattenUsers.reduce((a, e, i) => (i % 2 || a.push([]), a[a.length - 1].push(e), a), []);
  console.log("sorted:", sorted);
return Promise.resolve([sorted,users])
}
app.post('/api/login', apiLimiter, async function (req, res){


  try  {
  let [sorted,users] = await getSorted();
    console.log("sorted in /api/login:", sorted);
    console.log("Req firstname: ",req.body.firstname)
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    console.log("Hashed pw: ", hashedPassword);
    console.log(await bcrypt.compare('testtest',hashedPassword));
    // const user = { id: req.body.id, username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password };
    var user = new User({firstname: req.body.firstname, eMail: req.body.eMail, password: hashedPassword });
    sorted.forEach(async ([eMail, password]) => {
      let result = bcrypt.compareSync(password, users[eMail]);
        // result = true if hash = hashed pw
        console.log("Yeet");
      });
    });
    jwt2.sign({user}, 'secrethere', { expiresIn: '15min'}, (err, token) =>{
    res.json({
      token
    });
  });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeet doesn't get printed out :/ and the `console.log("sorted in /api/login:", sorted);` still prints out nothing probably because it's out of scope

Comment: Yeah, now the problem is because User.find is promise so you will need to put await before User.find.

Comment: Can you edit the answer accordingly? It throws me a syntax error the way you wrote it

Comment: @Munchkin here you go.

Comment: changed const to var now I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: users is not defined`. Updated the question to contain the full list of errors P.S Yeet was also not printed out

Comment: @Munchkin yeah sorry man it was the scope error, now you get the users from the first function too. I updated the answer.

Comment: Okey man, so now this is related to you bcrypt logic, you can't use async in foreach , please use promise.all .

Comment: where exactly do I use it?

Comment: You should wrap foreach into Promise.all, see this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362312/3255220

Comment: Could you write an example on how to implement it for my code?

Comment: @Munchkin sorry man,it's just the map with promises, read about promises. But  for now you can use compareSync instead of compare and don't care about promises. I updated the answer.

Comment: "Yeet" still doesn't get printed out and I still get errors :/ please check the updated question (update 3) for the errors

Comment: Just found out that according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241113/bcrypt-error-data-and-hash-arguments-required) one of my arguments is undefined, which is true - my users[eMail] for some reason is undefined :/ how do I fix it?

Comment: Managed to fix it.